# Spark sql to get a field value from a multi-level nested struct array

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say we have a table with below schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- info_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- info_status: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to get product_id as an array, is is possible to do this via pure spark sql?

Below sql result in a syntax error:

```
select info.details.products.product_id from table1

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'table1.`info`.`details`['products']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''products'' is of string type.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing **array of structs** you would need to give which element from **array** you need to access i.e 0,1,2..

For your case, try:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("info", ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("info_id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("info_status", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("details", ArrayType(
                StructType([
                    StructField("products", ArrayType(
                        StructType([
                            StructField("product_id", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("amount", IntegerType(), True),
                            StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True)
                        ])
                    ))
                ])
            ))
        ])
    ))
])

data = [
    ("1", [
        ("1", 1, [
            ([
                ("1", 10, 123456789),
                ("2", 20, 123456790)
            ],)
        ])
    ]),
    ("2", [
        ("2", 2, [
            ([
                ("3", 30, 123456791),
                ("4", 40, 123456792)
            ],),
            ([
                ("5", 50, 123456793),
                ("6", 60, 123456794)
            ],)
        ])
    ])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.selectExpr("info[0].details[0].products[0].product_id").show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|info[0].details[0].products[0].product_id|
+-----------------------------------------+
|1                                        |
|3                                        |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Update:

To get all `product_id` in this complex object as an array, you can try the following:

```
column_list = df.selectExpr("info[0].details[0].products[0].product_id as product_id").collect()
column_array = [row["product_id"] for row in column_list]
print(column_array)
> ['1', '3']
```

Comment: Similarly, to achieve the same result using Spark SQL, try `spark.sql("SELECT info[0].details[0].products[0].product_id FROM table1")`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this only get the first element, I want all product_id in this complex object as an array.

Comment: @gfytd extended my answer, hope this resolves your request

Comment: thanks, maybe I didn't describle my question clearly, for one id, I need to get ALL product ids, take 'data' above in your reply as an example, what I expect are 2 rows, for id 1, the product ids are [1,2], for id 2, the product ids are [3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out:

```
select flatten(flatten(info.details).products).product_id
from table1 where ...
```

For 2 dimensional array, I need to flatten it first.